# Shiny app to automatically update selectinput value

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app to predict probability of mortality after users have input values for some health-related questions. There is a select box asking their drinking status(heavy drinker,moderate drinker, and non-drinker), however, the definition for heavy drinker and moderate drinker differ by gender. So I would like the value for this select box to be automatically updated after users have input their gender. But the predicted probability won't be computed after user has input values for all of the questions and click the "submit" button.Below are part of my code:

ui.r

```
header<-dashboardHeader(title="Mortality Calculator")
sidebar<-dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
menuItem("Predicted Mortality", tabName = "prediction", icon =     icon("th")),
menuItem("Plot", icon = icon("line-chart"), tabName = "plot")
  )
 )

body<-dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
           box( 
             sliderInput(inputId="id.age", 
                           label="Age", 
                           min = 50,
                           max = 85,
                           value =50,
                           step=1),
             selectInput(inputId = "id.gender",
                         label = "Select your gender",
                         choices = c("Male","Female")),

                uiOutput('slider1'),
           submitButton("Update")))
)


dashboardPage(
skin = "yellow",
header,
sidebar,
body
)
```

server.r

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){

output$slider1 <- renderUI({
    slider2.value <- input$id.gender
if (slider2.value=="Male"){
  selectInput("id.drinkingstatus","Select your drinking status", 
              choices = c("Heavy Drinker(>2 drinks per day)","Moderate     Drinker(<=2 drinks per day)","Non-Drinker"))

} else{
  selectInput("id.drinkingstatus","Select your drinking status", 
              choices = c("Heavy Drinker(>1 drink per day)","Moderate  Drinker(<=1 drink per day)","Non-Drinker"))

}})
```

Right now, the drinking status select box won't update until user has clicked the submit button. Could anyone help me to modify the code so that the select box can be automatically updated? I have also tried the conditionalpanel but the problem remains. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Look into `updateSelectInput()` and embed it into an `observe()` statement which checks the gender selection.

Comment: You might also consider looking at [conditional panel](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html)